# android: TextToSpeech leaking service connection

Tags: java, android, service, text-to-speech, serviceconnection

I am trying to create an app using text to speech. Whenever I move from activity Text_entry to activity CombChange and back i receive these service connection leaked errors in the log cat (below).

Can anyone see why?

I have only pasted the relevant bits of the Text_Entry and CombChange classes - so there may be missing declarations and curly brackets etc.

```
public class Text_entry extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

    speech = new Speech(this);
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, CombChange.class);
    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent2.putExtra("newPat", enteredNumber);
    startActivity(intent2);
}

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String hc =" ";
        hc = intent.getExtras().getString("helpComb");
        if (hc.equals("true"))
            helpComb = true;
        else
            helpComb = false;
    }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                speech = new Speech(this);
            }
            else {
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
            }
    }
```

.

```
public class CombChange extends ListActivity {
    speech = new Speech(this);
    speech.changeText("enter the new combination");
    speech.speaks();
    SystemClock.sleep(1300);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Text_entry.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("helpComb", "true");
    speech.cleanUp();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

.

```
public class Speech implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private String toRead;
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    public Speech(Context c) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(c, this);
        tts.setPitch(1.2f);
        tts.setSpeechRate(1.5f);
    }
    public void speaks()
    {
        speakOut();
    }

    public void changeText(String changeTo)
    {
        toRead = changeTo;
    }


    public void cleanUp() {
         //Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
    }   


    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }
    protected void onStop()
    {

        if(tts != null){
            tts.shutdown();
        }       
    }
    private void speakOut() {
        tts.speak(toRead, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
```

.

```
03-21 16:42:32.515: I/TextToSpeech(24023): Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023): Activity org.BT.Text_entry has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@427fd290 that was originally bound here
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity org.BT.Text_entry has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@427fd290 that was originally bound here
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:965)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:859)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1344)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1336)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:401)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:627)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:597)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:553)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:527)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:512)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at org.BT.Speech.<init>(Speech.java:14)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at org.BT.Text_entry.onCreate(Text_entry.java:97)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-21 16:42:32.535: E/ActivityThread(24023):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 16:42:32.670: I/TextToSpeech(24023): Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
03-21 16:42:32.670: D/(24023): 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
03-21 16:42:32.670: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24023): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-21 16:42:32.670: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24023): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-21 16:42:32.775: I/TextToSpeech(24023): Connected to TTS Service
03-21 16:42:32.780: I/TextToSpeech(24023): Connected to TTS Service
```

Comment: Does your app actually run? In the class CombChange there are no method at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can solve your problem, however I cannot explain it in terms of your code - maybe someone else on here can 
http://www.stevenmarkford.com/android-activity-has-leaked-serviceconnection-that-was-originally-bound-here/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much this will help but Please try to implement onPause() method in Activity class. And unbind your service explicitly.
For ex:

```
@Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            CalculatorUser c=new CalculatorUser(); //your Activity name object
            c.unbindService((ServiceConnection) this);
        }
```

Unbinding might solve your issue and "Activity 'APP' has leaked ServiceConnection" happens mostly when you move out of your Activity So you need to explicitly tell to Android OS to please unbind me from services my Activity is using as of now. When again you will launch you App it will bind to service. If its not helpful sent me code i will try to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

ACTUAL ANSWER TO THIS PROBLEM:

You need to call `destroy()` on your `TextToSpeech` object when the service is destroyed.

I had this problem and saw your question so I thought I would answer it for anyone else who comes here.

Answer (score 0):

For me works to shutdown the TextToSpeech object.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    tts.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```